# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

I keep doing this over and over and can't figure out the source. Can someone take a look and see what I am doing wrong?

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as cell

    myCell.title.text = titles[indexPath.row]
    myCell.username.text = usernames[indexPath.row]

    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

            myCell.postedImage.image = image
        }


    }


    return myCell

}
```

The error shows:
Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint (code=1 etc.

Comment: does it tell  you which line cause the error?

Comment: I tried to post an image but it wouldnt let me unless 10 rep but is on the Variable line:

Comment: why you need to post an image? just tell us which line cause the error....

Comment: var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you registered a cell class with the TableView? The following was missing in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573420/xcode-beginner-having-run-time-error-on-simple-tableview-code/28573883#28573883):

```
self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

It's a different error message though, so I'm guessing it's not the same problem. Can you post more code from the TableViewController?

Comment: There was a comment on the post you linked. Thanks